# Mocking static classes with Powermock2 and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, powermock, powermockito

in Android I've been using the version **1.6.1** of Powermock and all this implementation worked really good for statics.
It's not working now at all when I changed to **2.0.0-beta.5**. Indeed, it didn't even work upgrading from my previous **1.6.1** to **1.7.1**.

I have this implementation:

```
// Power Mockito
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:2.0.0-beta.5"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5"
//testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.0-beta.5'

// Mockito
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0"
testImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin-kt1.1:1.5.0"
androidTestImplementation("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin-kt1.1:1.5.0", {
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
})
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.11.0'
```

and I'm trying to mock a static the same way I was doing with **1.6.1:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion::class, ConfigUseCaseTests::class)
class ConfigUseCaseTests {

    lateinit var context: Context

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        context = mock()
    }

    @Test
    fun getConfigs_fromJson() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion::class.java)

        val instance = mock<SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion>()
        doReturn("foo")
                .whenever(instance)
                .loadString(isA(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())
//        whenever(instance.loadString(isA(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("foo") // This shows the same error
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion::class.java)
                .withAnyArguments()
                .thenReturn(instance)

        val mockedFoo = instance.loadString(context, "", "", "") // This shows "foo"

        val mockedCompanion = SharedPreferencesHelper.loadString(context, "", "", "") // This is throwing NullPointerException

        Assert.assertEquals(mockedCompanion, "foo")
    }
}
```

My **SharedPreferencesHelper** looks like:

```
class SharedPreferencesHelper {
    companion object {

        @Suppress("NON_FINAL_MEMBER_IN_OBJECT")
        open fun loadString(context: Context, fileName: String, key: String, defaultValue: String?): String? {
            val sharedPreferences = getWithFileName(context, fileName)
            return if (!sharedPreferences.contains(key)) {
                defaultValue
            } else {
                sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to play with the `open` but it didn't work.

**Exception:** (I don't understand it at all)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.package.ConfigUseCaseTests.getConfigs_fromJson(ConfigUseCaseTests.kt:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
```

I can say, sometimes IT WORKS!! I'm adding the video because it looks amazing that it happens just sometimes:
https://youtu.be/YZObVLcERBo (watch at the middle and the end)

Comment: I know you will not like my statement because it does not solve the problem the way you want to, but that's why I am posting it as a comment. Maybe you want to consider the advice of someone who has been coaching developers for many years, also about test automation and making applications more testable: **Don't use PowerMock, it is a code smell!** Whenever you feel the urge to use it, it is a clear sign that instead you should refactor your code for testability. If I would look into your question in order to solve it with PowerMock, then only from a "sports" perspective as a finger exercise.

Comment: @Rafael Ruiz Muñoz, You got any solution for this??

Comment: @bGorle yes, migrating to MockK. The easiest option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Wrote some tests with mockk initially tests are working after some time they were not working, Then tried to mock with powermock mockstatic. Removed the powermock-agent dependency now mockk is working.

Answer (score 1):

The way companion objects are created on compilation is by creating a static field inside the surrounding class. It get's instantiated on the static scope (before the test is instantiated).

This is how it looks when decompiled in `Java`:

```
public final class SharedPreferencesHelper {
  public static final SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion Companion = new 
  SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
  // ...
}
```

For this to work you'll have to assign the given field with your mock instead of intercepting the creation of the `Companion` object. This doesn't even require to use `PowerMock` and can be done with reflexion: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-change-private-static-final-fields

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this answer seems to be more like the definition of a Static/Companion class in Kotlin. Indeed I'm saying I want to mock the Companion by `PowerMockito.mockStatic(SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion::class.java)` and of course I'm telling PowerMockito to mock the constructor with any arguments ` PowerMockito.whenNew(SharedPreferencesHelper.Companion::class.java)`